# How to publish custom artifacts with `com.gradle.plugin-publish` plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use ProGuard to minimize my gradle plugin and it works well, producing the output file `a-min.jar`

However, `com.gradle.plugin-publish` plugin just doesn't recognize it when using task `publishPlugins`, it tells

> Cannot determine main artifact to upload - could not find jar artifact with empty classifier

Strangely, when using `publishToMavenLocal` it did work well.

I've tried some tricks to replace the main jar with my processed jar, but always failed. Is there any new sight here?

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            withType<MavenPublication> {
                if (name == "pluginMaven") {
                    setArtifacts(listOf(
                        artifact(minJarPath){
                            classifier = ""
                            extension = "jar"
                        }
                    ))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to decompile `com.gradle.plugin-publish:0.18.0`, getting that

```java
  private File findMainArtifact() {
    if (this.useAutomatedPublishing) {
      for (UsageContext variant : this.javaRuntimeVariants) {
        for (PublishArtifact artifact : variant.getArtifacts()) {
          if (Util.isBlank(artifact.getClassifier()) && "jar".equals(artifact.getExtension()))
            return artifact.getFile(); 
        } 
      } 
    } else {
      Configuration archivesConfiguration = getProject().getConfigurations().getByName("archives");
      for (PublishArtifact artifact : archivesConfiguration.getAllArtifacts()) {
        if (Util.isBlank(artifact.getClassifier()) && "jar".equals(artifact.getExtension()))
          return artifact.getFile(); 
      } 
    } 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot determine main artifact to upload - could not find jar artifact with empty classifier");
  }
```

But I don't know how to add a artifact to "AllArtifacts".

Full code: [GitHub@ArcticLampyrid/gradle-git-version](https://github.com/ArcticLampyrid/gradle-git-version/blob/0bec0c0ce7c44ffb1e866587919ac33a57733814/build.gradle.kts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved** by some tricks although it is not elegant.

## Solution

1. Create a real jar task to include proguard outputs and add it to outgoing of apiElements & runtimeElements.
   Delete the unprocessed jar from apiElements & runtimeElements. (for `publishPlugins` task)
2. Also, modify publications (for `publishToMavenLocal` task)

## Example

```kotlin
/* Written in Kotlin DSL for Gradle */
/* build.gradle.kts */

// for `publishPlugins` task
val minJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class){
    dependsOn(genMinJar)
    from(zipTree(minJarPath))
}
jar {
    archiveClassifier.set("unpacked")
}
configurations {
    artifacts {
        arrayOf(apiElements, runtimeElements).forEach {
            it.get().outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it.classifier == "unpacked" }
            it.get().outgoing.artifact(minJar)
        }
    }
}

// for `publishToMavenLocal` task
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            withType<MavenPublication> {
                if (name == "pluginMaven") {
                    setArtifacts(listOf(minJar))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Details

See https://github.com/ArcticLampyrid/gradle-git-version/commit/23ccfc8bdf16c9352024dc0b7722f534a310551f